# Create and configure custom plugin in yum

Tags: python, plugins, centos, yum

1. I want to write a custom yum plugin to install packages from a single repository containing multiple directories. The directories could be like release, dev, testing, hotfix etc. I want that the client can have the capability to install packages from these directories e.g.: If the client just wants to install the packages from hotfix directory then the plugin should be able to do that. Any pointers or sample code would be of great help.
2. How to configure a custom plugin in yum. I searched google but couldn't find much apart from the default plugins like security, downloadonly etc... which are already part of yum

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the goal here but why are you trying to use a yum plugin for this instead of just independent repositories (or a combined repository if that works for your goal)?

Comment: @Etan I cannot have independent repositories, I need to have a combined repository and multiple directories in the repository and  each directory can contain hundreds of packages and I want to provide the client an option to update package from specific directory rather than updating all the packages found in the combined repository. Hope I was able to clear things for you. Let me know if you still have any doubts about what I am trying to achieve here.

Comment: I don't know that you can limit updates to files located under certain paths in a repository. I've certainly never seen or done it. Is there a reason this cannot be separate repositories? Because that would be much easier.

Comment: As to writing a plugin the second google search result for `yum plugins` for me is [this link](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/WritingYumPlugins).

Comment: Yes I think the same that having separate repositories would be easier and then using disablerepo and enablerepo command options but the requirement is to have a single repository and to write a plugin to provide option to client to update packages from specific directories e.g.: hotfix would be a directory which will contain packages provided for a hotfix and the client can update the package only from hotfix directory rather than updating all the other available packages.

Comment: You might be able to hook `preresolve` or something like that and then walk all the available packages from the repository and manually delete/exclude ones from the "wrong" directories from the package lists but I don't know if that's actually possible or if it will work at all well. This just really isn't how this is supposed to work as far as I know. An alternative would be to use the `%{dist}` tag in the `%{release}` field and tag each directories packages with a different tag and then always upgrade via glob or something (but that's ugly and prone to failure).